# What is the best way to programmatically log into a web site in order to screen scrape? (Preferably in Python)

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I want to be able to log into a website programmatically and periodically obtain some information from the site. What is the best tool(s) that would make this as simple as possible? I'd prefer a Python library of some type because I want to become more proficient in Python, but I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

You can try Mechanize (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for programmatic web-browsing, and definitely use Beautiful Soup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for the scraping.

Answer (score 3):

Most of us use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to get the page; it can handle various forms of authentication and cookie collection.  Then [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the results.

Answer (score 2):

I once wrote a Python script to automatically log into vBulletin forums. The difficult part was knowing how to correctly form the login request and that is something that a library won't help you with. I found [Live Http Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) - an addon for Firefox - to be pretty helpful in seeing what is sent between the client and server during the login process.

I also agree with everyone else that Beautiful Soup is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend using [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) it makes it a snap to do the login procedure.  then use beautifulsoup etc.
 as described above. ive never tried mechanize, but it looks pretty good.

Comment: twill is essentially a thin shell around the mechanize package.

Answer (score 0):

just for screen scraping you can use combination of url lib + pyqyery. 
https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/